# prevent npm from removing node_modules folder on failure

Tags: npm

I want to `npm install` a broken package, i.e., the installation process does not work properly and results in an error. I am used to `npm` keeping the successfully installed packages in the local `node_modules` folder. For some reason `npm` has stopped doing that and removes the `node_modules` folder if the install is not successful.

**How can I tell npm to keep the local `node_modules` folder regardless of the success or failure of the installation process?**

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem when one of the packages failed to build its C++ addon and npm removed node_modules. The below steps helped me:

Install the packages with scripts disabled.

```
$ npm install --ignore-scripts
```

Fix the package

...

Rebuild the package

```
$ npm rebuild PACKAGE
```